# Configuracion incorrecta de una migración en EF Core e Identity con ASP.net y Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, identity

Bajo el principio de "code first" intento crear una base de datos con ASP.net Core utilizando EF Core e Identity a través de las entidades o clases creadas. Para la tabla de usuarios quiero utilizar mi propia entidad o clase al igual que para los roles que estos van a desempeñar. Por ello mis clases heredan de IdentityUser e IdentityRole:

```
public class Usuario : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Apellidos { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Dni { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CategoriaId { get; set; }

    [Phone]
    public string Telefono { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    public string Mail { get; set; }

    public Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
    public List<Mensaje> Mensajes { get; set; } 
    public List<Notificacion> Notificaciones { get; set; } 
    public List<RegistroJornada> Jornadas { get; set; }
    public List<SolicitudCambio> SolicitudesSolicitante { get; set; } 
    public List<SolicitudCambio> SolicitudesSolicitado { get; set; }
    public ArchivoAdjunto ArchivoAdjunto { get; set; }

}

public class Categoria : IdentityRole
{
    
    [Required]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

}
```

Como se ve hay otras propiedades de navegación para el resto de tablas que quiero crear.
En mi DBContext he especificado algunas relaciones ya que si no la migración no se llegaba a crear:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext: IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext (DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().Property(p => p.UserId).HasMaxLength(256);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().Property(p => p.RoleId).HasMaxLength(256);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
    .HasOne(u => u.Categoria)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(u => u.CategoriaId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Mensaje>()
    .HasOne(m => m.Emisor)    // Configura la relación de navegación
    .WithMany(u => u.Mensajes) // Indica la propiedad de navegación inversa en Usuario
    .HasForeignKey(m => m.EmisorId)   // Indica la clave foránea en Mensaje
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); // Configura el comportamiento de eliminación si es necesario

        modelBuilder.Entity<SolicitudCambio>()
    .HasOne(m => m.UsuarioSolicitado)    // Configura la relación de navegación
    .WithMany(u => u.SolicitudesSolicitado) // Indica la propiedad de navegación inversa en Usuario
    .HasForeignKey(m => m.UsuarioSolicitadoId)// Indica la clave foránea en Mensaje
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); // Configura el comportamiento de eliminación si es necesario

        
    }

    public DbSet<Turno> Turnos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EstadoSolicitud> EstadoSolicitudes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Categoria> Categorias { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SolicitudCambio> SolicitudesCambios { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RegistroJornada> RegistroJornadas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Notificacion> Notificaciones { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Mensaje> Mensajes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ArchivoAdjunto> ArchivosAdjuntos { get; set; }
}
```

En la clase Program.cs tengo añadida la siguiente configuración:

```
// Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(opciones =>
            opciones.UseSqlServer("name=DefaultConnection"));

        builder.Services.AddAuthentication();

        //Configuramos la tabla Usuarios y Roles en base a nuestras clases
        builder.Services.AddIdentity<Usuario, Categoria>(opciones =>
        {
            opciones.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        var app = builder.Build();
```

La migracion se crea correctamente, pero cuando hago Update-Database en la consola de administrador de paquetes aparecen los siguentes avisos:

```
Failed executing DbCommand (7ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', 
CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [AspNetUserRoles] (
[UserId] nvarchar(256) NOT NULL,
[RoleId] nvarchar(256) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetUserRoles] PRIMARY KEY ([UserId], [RoleId]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetRoles_RoleId] FOREIGN KEY ([RoleId]) REFERENCES 
[AspNetRoles] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES 
[AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): La columna
> 'AspNetRoles.Id' no tiene la misma longitud o escala que la columna de
> referencia 'AspNetUserRoles.RoleId' en la clave externa
> 'FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetRoles_RoleId'. Las columnas que participan
> en una relación de claves externas deben estar definidas con la misma
> longitud y escala. No se pudo crear la restricción o el índice. Vea
> los errores anteriores. Advertencia: la máxima longitud de clave para
> un índice agrupado es de 900 bytes. El índice 'PK_AspNetUserRoles'
> tiene una longitud máxima de 1024 bytes. Para algunas combinaciones de
> valores grandes, la operación de inserción o actualización no
> funcionará correctamente.    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
> Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
> SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
> BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String
> methodName, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String methodName)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1
> migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String
> targetMigration)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String
> targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String
> targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
> action) ClientConnectionId:a1c16c08-5a8a-4979-b71a-8bd67fb2860c Error
> Number:1753,State:0,Class:16
>
> La columna 'AspNetRoles.Id' no tiene la misma longitud o escala que la
> columna de referencia 'AspNetUserRoles.RoleId' en la clave externa
> 'FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetRoles_RoleId'. Las columnas que participan
> en una relación de claves externas deben estar definidas con la misma
> longitud y escala.
>
> No se pudo crear la restricción o el índice. Vea los errores
> anteriores. Advertencia: la máxima longitud de clave para un índice
> agrupado es de 900 bytes. El índice 'PK_AspNetUserRoles' tiene una
> longitud máxima de 1024 bytes. Para algunas combinaciones de valores
> grandes, la operación de inserción o actualización no funcionará
> correctamente.

Pienso que son estas 2 clases citadas al principio las que dan problema pero no se exactamente cual es la modificación que debo hacer para evitar esto utilizando EF Core e Identity. Tal vez es mejor dejar las tablas por defecto de Identity para Usuario y su rol aunque me gustaría saber donde radica el error.

Comment: como definiste las dos columnas.. tienen que ser exactamente iguales...

Comment: Vale, claro. Al estar relacionados estos campos en diferentes tablas si no cambio al mismo tamaño los campos relacionados falla. Esa configuración me faltaba.